# MS Build Conditions

Tags: build, msbuild, build-automation

I have a couple of conditional statements in a property group of a project:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I am trying to figure out what they mean? `Condition = blank` and `Platform = blank`? But then the tags have the actual data? How does that actually interpret?

Does it mean that the Configuration can be anything and the platform can be anything, or does it mean that the property group only applies to Configuration=Debug|Platform=x86?

If my assumption is correct, can I just copy the entire property group and set the values for configuration and platform to `Release` and `AnyCPU` as follows:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Release</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the property `Configuration == ''` then set it to Debug its the same for Platform in effect you are setting a default when one is not specified

Comment: So the values inside the tags are defaults, but the actual configuration and platform passed to msbuild via parameters: `/p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=AnyCPU` overide the defaults?